# Yii Framework PHP redirect to external Link in new tab?

Tags: php, redirect, yii

Hi what i essentially want to achieve is a redirect to an external link in a new tab right now I've got:

```
$this->redirect('http://www.google.com', array('target'=>'_blank'));
```

Which redirects but not in a new tab...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey check out for this may be it will helpful for you 
`<?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text','http://google.com', array('target'=>'_blank')); ?>`

Comment: @lawrence if my answer is little useful to you.i would be glad if you will accept and voteup my answer. so someone can use in future if they want to do the same

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect in a new tab like this, as there's no way to specify the target in the Location http header.

A possible workaround is to output a form and submit it immediately with JS:

```
<form action="http://www.google.com" method="get" target="_blank" id="myform"></form>
<script>
  document.getElementById("myform").submit();
</script>
```

Note that you'll somehow need to hide it in your main content, that appears in the current tab.